# VS2022 what needs to be install for "import std.core" to compile?

Tags: g++, visual-studio-2022

When I use the following:

```cpp
import std.core;
```

I get the error:

```
Error   C1011   cannot locate standard module interface. Did you install the library part of the C++ modules feature in VS setup?
```

I checked the install and I could not find how to install the C++ modules feature. I'm also concerned that this will not be standard enough to compile on both gcc 11.2.0 and VS2022.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Visual Studio Installer and make sure **C++ Modules for v143 build tools (x64/x86 - experimental)** is installed.
2. Open your project, go to **Properties -> C/C++ -> Languages -> Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules** and set it to **Yes (/experimental:module))**

It's still an experimental feature, so you may get some C5050 warning when importing std modules. For more information, you can visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1):

MS "jumped the gun" when they introduced "import std.core;" before C++23 officially adopted how to import modules groups.  With C++23 you either import std; or std.compat;

And with the latest VS 2022 versions even for C++23 you no longer need to enable the experimental module feature.  Just make sure your language standard is Preview, /std::c++latest.