# Why do I import std.core but not std?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, c++-modules

I did the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343093/vs2022-what-needs-to-be-install-for-import-std-core-to-compile) with MSVC2022 and was able to do:

```
import std.core;
```

but not

```
import std;
```

what is the difference? What is this `std.core`?

Comment: `import std;` is a C++23 feature, that AFAIK no compiler has yet implemented. `import std.core;` is a Microsoft specific module

Comment: Interesting.  Welcome back `bits/stdc++.h`.

Comment: See [Overview of modules in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170) on MSDN, in particulaar [Consume the C++ Standard Library as modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#consume-the-c-standard-library-as-modules), which describes the `std.core` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66379999/difference-between-import-and-include-cpp20/66380107#66380107) carefully, the problem is similar to yours.

And usually, In MSVS `std` refers to `namespace`, you could use the contents of std by adding `using namespace std;`, such as std::cout, etc.